# Getting field values in multiple levels of subclasses with Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, mono, field

So I have this object with multiple levels of subclasses, like so (not actual object but an abstraction to convey it's structure):

```
public class MasterType
{
    public TypeA typeA = new TypeA();
    public TypeB typeB = new TypeB();

    public class TypeA
    {
        public SubTypeA subTypeA = new SubTypeA();
        public SubTypeB subTypeB = new SubTypeB();

        public class SubTypeA
        {
            public int Field1 = 10;
        }

        public class SubTypeB
        {
            public int Field2 = 20;
        }
    }

    public class typeB
    {
        public int Field3 = 30;
    }
}
```

I've tried to extract the fields of TypeA and it's subclasses (SubTypeA and SubTypeB) like so:

```
foreach (var t in MasterType.TypeA.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy))
{
    foreach (var field in t.FieldType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(field.Name + " | " + field.GetValue(t.FieldType));
    }
}
```

But I get this exception:

```
ArgumentException: Field 'Field1' defined on type 'SubTypeA' is not a field on the target object which is of type 'MonoType'.
```

Printing the FieldType for t yields the expected result 'SubTypeA' etc.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I smell an "XY Problem" -- why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong?

Yes - in this expression:

```
field.GetValue( t.FieldType )
```

The parameter passed to `GetValue` should be an instance of the type that defines the field. It should be the object that contains the particular field value you want to get.

`t.FieldType` is an instance of the type `System.Type`

Comment: I see. Indeed, specifying the type directly worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your `GetValue` requires instances of classes `SubTypeA` and `SubTypeB`, which fields must be received, but you pass a `Type` instance.

Try this way:

```
        MasterType value = new MasterType();
        foreach (var t in typeof(MasterType.TypeA).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy))
        {
            var fieldValue = t.GetValue(value.typeA);
            foreach (var field in t.FieldType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(field.Name + " | " + field.GetValue(fieldValue));
            }
        }
```

At first you need to create `MasterType` instance, after that you should get values of `subTypeA` and `subTypeB` which are in `value.typeA`.
These values will be passed as arguments for `GetValue` in nested foreach.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following code works:

```
foreach (var fieldInfo in typeof(MasterType.TypeA).GetFields())
{
 Console.WriteLine(fieldInfo);
}
```

*GetType* is instance method and not static. To get Type object, you need to use *typeof*.